# @EnableSpringConfigured import

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, import

hi i am working with a spring mvc project and i want to be able to do this annotation

> @EnableSpringConfigured

in the top of one of my classes like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured  <---- this one gives me troubles
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.abc.dom", "com.abc.repo", "com.abc.auth"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.abc.repo")
public class ConfigJPA 
{

....

}
```

what maven dependency should i have in my pom.xml to be able to do this import:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.EnableSpringConfigured;
```

my spring version is 4.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.aspects&version=3.2.0.RELEASE&searchType=bundlesByClass&searchQuery=springframework&showAll=true

Comment: it gives me two errors 
1) Missing artifact org.springframework:org.springframework.aspects:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE

2) 
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Users\myUSer\.m2\repository\org\springframework\org.springframework.aspects\3.2.0.RELEASE\org.springframework.aspects-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar' 

i am using spring tools suite and everytime i add a dependency i use the option update project using maven, but i dont know why it dont find this jar

Comment: this is how i added it
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 7):

this is how i added the dependency and it worked

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Reimeus the link to the page that you give the artifactId was added like this

```
<artifactId>org.springframework.aspects</artifactId>
```

instead like `<artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>` thats why it dont worked for me, but thanks anyway it helped me too